# How to properly dispose of Connected Display Window and View?

Tags: swift, nsview, nswindow

I have code that opens a window and displays a view on a connected display.  My goal is to detect a connection/disconnection of a connected display and show/remove the view accordingly.  I have that part working fine.

The problem I am having is closing the window upon disconnection, but then if a subsequent connection is made, and upon creating the window and view again, I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

I tried a different approach by setting the `connectedDisplayWindow` and `connectedDisplayView` to `nil`, after calling `close()` on the window when a connected display is removed.  Maybe I am misunderstanding the `close()` method?

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419662-close)

> If the window is set to be released when closed, a release message is sent to the object after the current event is completed. For an NSWindow object, the default is to be released on closing, while for an NSPanel object, the default is not to be released. You can use the isReleasedWhenClosed property to change the default behavior...

Just to make sure, I tried setting the `isReleasedWhenClosed` to true, but it did not change the problem.

The other thing I see in the console is about seven repeated error strings immediately upon disconnection of the connected display: `2022-04-10 10:28:11.044155-0500 External Display[95744:4934855] [default] invalid display identifier 67EE0C44-4E3D-3AF2-3447-A867F9FC477D` before the notification is fired, and one more after the notification occurs: `2022-04-10 10:28:11.067555-0500 External Display[95744:4934855] [default] Invalid display 0x4e801884`.  Could these be related to the issues I am having?

Full example code:

ViewController.swift

```
import Cocoa

let observatory = NotificationCenter.default

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var connectedDisplay: NSScreen?
    var connectedDisplayWindow: NSWindow?
    var connectedDisplayView: NSView?
    var connectedDisplayCount: Int = 0
    var connectedDisplayID: UInt32 = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setupObservatory()
        if NSScreen.screens.count > 1 {
            handleDisplayConnectionChange(notification: nil)
        }
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear() {
        connectedDisplayWindow?.close()
    }
    
    func setupObservatory() {
        observatory.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleDisplayConnectionChange), name: NSApplication.didChangeScreenParametersNotification, object: nil)
        observatory.addObserver(forName: .setupConnectedDisplayWindow, object: nil, queue: nil, using: setupConnectedDisplayWindow)
    }
    
    @objc func handleDisplayConnectionChange(notification: Notification?) {
        if connectedDisplayCount != NSScreen.screens.count {
            if connectedDisplayCount < NSScreen.screens.count {
                print("There is a connected display.")
                connectedDisplayCount = NSScreen.screens.count
                if let _ = NSScreen.screens.last {
                    if connectedDisplay != NSScreen.screens.last {
                        connectedDisplayID = NSScreen.screens.last!.displayID!
                        connectedDisplay = NSScreen.screens.last!
                    }
                } else {
                    connectedDisplayID = 0
                }
                if connectedDisplayID != 0 && !connectedDisplayIsActive {
                    observatory.post(name: .setupConnectedDisplayWindow, object: nil)
                }
            } else if connectedDisplayCount > NSScreen.screens.count {
                print("A connected display was removed.")
                connectedDisplayCount = NSScreen.screens.count
                connectedDisplayIsActive = false
                connectedDisplayWindow?.close()
                //connectedDisplayView = nil <- causes error @main in AppDelegate
                //connectedDisplayWindow = nil <- causes error @main in AppDelegate
                connectedDisplay = nil
                connectedDisplayID = 0
            }
        }
    }
    
    func setupConnectedDisplayWindow(notification: Notification) {
        if NSScreen.screens.count > 1 && !connectedDisplayIsActive {
            connectedDisplay = NSScreen.screens.last
            let mask: NSWindow.StyleMask = [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable]
            connectedDisplayWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: connectedDisplay!.frame, styleMask: mask, backing: .buffered, defer: true, screen: connectedDisplay) // <- causes error on subsequent connection
            connectedDisplayWindow?.level = .normal
            connectedDisplayWindow?.isOpaque = false
            connectedDisplayWindow?.backgroundColor = .clear
            connectedDisplayWindow?.hidesOnDeactivate = false
            let viewRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: connectedDisplay!.frame.width, height: connectedDisplay!.frame.height)
            connectedDisplayView = ConnectedDisplayView(frame: viewRect)
            connectedDisplayWindow?.contentView = connectedDisplayView
            connectedDisplayWindow?.orderFront(nil)
            connectedDisplayView?.window?.toggleFullScreen(self)
            connectedDisplayIsActive = true
            observatory.post(name: .setupConnectedDisplayView, object: nil)
        }
    }
}

extension Notification.Name {
    static var setupConnectedDisplayWindow: Notification.Name {
        return .init(rawValue: "ViewController.setupConnectedDisplayView")
    }
    static var setupConnectedDisplayView: Notification.Name {
        return .init(rawValue: "ConnectedDisplayView.setupConnectedDisplayView")
    }
}

extension NSScreen {
    var displayID: CGDirectDisplayID? {
        return deviceDescription[NSDeviceDescriptionKey(rawValue: "NSScreenNumber")] as? CGDirectDisplayID
    }
}
```

ConnectedDisplayView.swift

```
import Cocoa

var connectedDisplayIsActive: Bool = false

class ConnectedDisplayView: NSView {
    
    var imageView: NSImageView!

    override init(frame: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupObservatory()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupObservatory() {
        observatory.addObserver(forName: .setupConnectedDisplayView, object: nil, queue: nil, using: setupConnectedDisplayView)
    }
    
    func setupConnectedDisplayView(notification: Notification) {
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Shared/my image.png")
        if let image = NSImage(contentsOf: imageURL) {
            imageView = NSImageView(image: image)
            imageView.wantsLayer = true
            imageView.frame = self.frame
            imageView.alphaValue = 1
            self.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

I commented out the nil settings for the `connectedDisplayWindow` and `connectedDisplayView` objects and the error at `@main` in AppDelegate went away, but then I get an error when trying to reinitialize the `connectedDisplayWindow` if the connected display is removed or the connection is momentarily interrupted.

Comment: I tried creating a subclass of NSWindow, but the required initializer does not allow the use of the `screen` parameter, so I cannot subclass NSWindow for this purpose as far I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of `isReleasedWhenClosed` is `true` and `connectedDisplayWindow?.close()` releases the window. Setting `connectedDisplayWindow` to `nil` or to another window releases the window again and causes a crash. Solution: set `isReleasedWhenClosed` to `false`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my crash!  In my testing I was not able to set the connectedDisplayWindow object to nil after the `close()` without a crash, even though I declared it as an optional.  Setting `isReleasedWhenClosed` to `false` I am now able to set the connectedDisplayWindow to nil after the `close()` call without a crash. So I guess I misunderstood what release meant.  I guess it means when an object is released it is completely destroyed and not reusable?

Comment: `release` is the same as removing a strong reference. If the last strong reference is removed then the object is deallocated and unusable. After that, removing a strong reference by `connectedDisplayWindow = nil` will crash.

Comment: Ah ha.  Okay, I didn’t know that.  Thanks for the follow up explanation! No idea why my question was down voted.  Is it a bad question?